# Searching file content

Tags: wpf

I have a folder with lot of files like doc, excel, ppt etc. Once the user selects a category from the combo I have assigned keywords related to the particular selection. My wpf application has to search the entire folder and content of the files for the key words and display the matching files in a gridview. Speed and performance also has to be maintained

How should I code this functionality?

Comment: do u have the solution pls post it

Comment: I am not even a C# programmer, but I know that [adding a bit more information will help you get a better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF part of your query is fairly straight-forward; just set the ItemsSource of your target control to a search result...

```
List<string> MyKeyWords = GetKeywords();

var allDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(SearchDirectoryName).GetDirectories("*",              SearchOption.AllDirectories);

myGrid.ItemsSource = (from di in allDirectories from fi in di.GetFiles() where HasKeyWordMatch(fi, MyKeyWords) select fi);
```

And then have the grid bind to the appropriate properties in a data template.

More difficult to address is the `'HasKeyWordMatch'` predicate, which presumably takes a FileInfo object and a list of key words and returns a true/false if a match was found.  As you want to scan proprietary formats, you'll need to write a scanning engine for each format.

Comment: thanks for the reply and can u pls post the code. First thins is i have the directory path and based on the key words i need to search in the entire directory in each file contents and return the matched files and display in it a grid view and also speed and performance is the key note!!!!

Comment: Depending upon the number of processors on your box, you can gain performance by adding 'AsParallel()' to each of the projections.  As to posting the code, it's in the above article.  I tested it against a directory with 28k files in it.

Comment: tannks garry partially working will update you the progress and if anything required!!!! and any help for HasKeyWordMatch(fi, MyKeyWords) logic ????

Comment: I would define an interface from which all parsing engines inherit and then populate a dictionary with their concrete instances, the dictionary being keyed by file extension.  I emphatically suggest not to create concrete instances in your code,  but rather to create them from config strings.

Comment: can u pls post the code for searching keywords and the logic in HasKeyWordMatch(fi, MyKeyWords)

Comment: Hey garry thanks for replying constantly!!!! i have achived it with the below predicate StreamReader testTxt = new StreamReader(fi.FullName);
                string allRead = testTxt.ReadToEnd();
                testTxt.Close(); 
                string regMatch = "string";
                if (Regex.IsMatch(allRead, regMatch))
                {
                    return true;

                }

Comment: garry quick question, i am using the logic which is suggested by you but for a folder with 100 files it is taking alomost 20 sec to search and display can u suggest me how to improve the speed!!!

Comment: I would suggest you open another question and put your code there.  Your new question has to do with performance and will attract the attention of people with a performance speciality.  I would need to see the code too.  A new question is the way to go on this one.  Be sure to include the performance tag too.  I will look at it when it's ready also.

Comment: Thanks Garry i have implemented lucene.net and i have achived wht i am looking and thanks for all the help!!! i am going to open new thred "how to view files like doc,pdf,xls,ppt,html in wpf" kindly request u to help me !!! thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have the link for your new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612989/view-files-pdf-doc-excel-ppts-html-in-wpf-3-5

Comment: Garry below is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612989/view-files-pdf-doc-excel-ppts-html-in-wpf-3-5  kindly request u to post the code

Comment: garry if possible pls see the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667471/lucene-net-searching-file-content